# Java 8: Supplier working with files throws "stream has already been operated upon or closed"

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Working with `JUnit` and `Stream` I have the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

I did a research, and is clear is **not** possible reuse a stream

**But** according with this post:

- [Java – Stream has already been operated upon or closed](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-stream-has-already-been-operated-upon-or-closed)

working with `Supplier` is possible work around with this problem.

So my current code is the following:

```
    try (Stream<String> stream =  Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)) ) {

        Supplier<Stream<String>> supplier = () -> stream;

        logger.info("A");
        logger.info("ABC {}", supplier.get().findFirst().get());
        logger.info("B");
        logger.info("XYZ {}", supplier.get().skip(1050).findFirst().get());
        logger.info("C");

        assertThat(supplier.get().count(), is(1051));

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("{}", e.getMessage());
    }
```

How you can see I use the `supplier.get()` to work with the `Stream` (*it according with the tutorial*), but the `@Test` prints until **B**, therefore the `@Test` fails in `supplier.get().skip(1050).findFirst().get()` and it is still generating the same error message.

The unique difference between my code and the tutorial, the mime works through a File and the tutorial works around an array.

Something special to edit to work without any problem?

**Alpha**

I did the following edition (according with the snippet code of Eugene)

```
   try (Stream<String> stream =  Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)) ) {

        Supplier<Stream<String>> supplier = () -> stream.collect(Collectors.toList()).stream();

        logger.info("A");
        logger.info("ABC {}", supplier.get().findFirst().get());
        logger.info("B");
        logger.info("XYZ {}", supplier.get().skip(1050).findFirst().get());
        logger.info("C");

        assertThat(supplier.get().count(), is(1051));

    }
```

Same error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Supplier` is no magic, you still need to provide a *new Stream* all the time from that Supplier.

So you could do:

```
Supplier<Stream<String>> supplier = () -> Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
```

But that would mean to read the file, all the time. You could read all the lines into a single `List`, store that in memory and `stream` out of that.

```
List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));

Supplier<Stream<String>> supplier = () -> allLines.stream();
```

Notice that even the tutorial that you have linked returns a new Stream, created via `Stream.of` like so:

```
 Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> Stream.of(array);
```

Comment: You could use `Files.readAllLines(...)` which returns a list directly.

Comment: Thanks, seems I am doing something wrong. See `Alpha` section in my original post

Comment: @ManuelJordan you are using and consuming the same `stream` all the time.

Comment: @ManuelJordan you can't reuse a stream in lambda when you reuse a lambda more than once.

Comment: But it contradicts the entire concept of logging frameworks to read a file unconditionally, just for serving logging statements which might be no-ops, depending on the configured logging level…

Answer (score 3):

This is because your supplier always provides the same instance of `Stream`, and you consume it already with `findFirst()`. Then you try to consume it again with `findFirst()`, and this is not allowed.

In the tutorial, a new stream is created each time. In your case, you would have to call `Files.lines()` inside your supplier to make it work, although that would mean you re-read the file every time.

Comment: Thanks, if you can share some snippet code would be more valuable, thanks.

Comment: Well @Eugene already did, simply use `readAllLines()` to get the list of lines from the file, and then create the stream out of it each time in your supplier, using the code he provided.