# Java 8 stream concatenate log files by prefix

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of rolling log files, say:

```
thread1.2018-04-09.log
thread1.2018-04-10.log
thread1.2018-04-11.log
thread2.2018-04-09.log
thread2.2018-04-10.log
thread2.2018-04-11.log
```

I want to concatenate all log files of each thread to process the files as if there was only one file per thread.

I started by parsing all files individually:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("path/to/log/folder"),
                    path -> path.toString().endsWith(".log"))
                    .forEach(this::parseLog);
```

And then merged the output by manually checking what thread generated the file. Not optimal...

Can I concatenate the streams of the files with the same prefix directly in the stream operation?

**Edit:**

Following suggestions in the comments, here is what I came up with:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().readLogs();
    }

    public void readLogs() {
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get("."))
                .filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".log"))) {

            Map<String, List<Path>> pathsByThread = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::getThreadName));

            for (String threadName : pathsByThread.keySet()) {
                pathsByThread.get(threadName).stream().flatMap(this::readAllLines).forEach(this::parseLogLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getThreadName(Path path) {
        int index = path.getFileName().toString().indexOf(".");

        return path.getFileName().toString().substring(0, index);
    }

    private Stream<String> readAllLines(Path path) {
        try (Stream<String> fileContent = Files.lines(path)) {
            return fileContent;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void parseLogLine(String line) {
        // Do something smart
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

I have a runtime error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
```

Comment: I would use `.flatMap(Files::lines)`

Comment: But flatMap would then create one big stream of lines, wouldn't it? What I want is to have a stream of lines for each thread log, i.e. one stream for thread1.*.log and one for thread2*.log

Comment: Group them first, process each group.

Comment: .flatMap(Files::lines) is not possible since Files::lines throws an IOException that can't be catched in flatMap. See the question edit for how to do it

Comment: it might be that Files.lines returns the same stream if the input is the same file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506038/java-8-supplier-working-with-files-throws-stream-has-already-been-operated-upo

Comment: try returning List<String> from readAllLines instead of Stream<String>

Comment: That does not compile: Error:(45, 55) java: method flatMap in interface java.util.stream.Stream<T> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Function<? super java.nio.file.Path,? extends java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>>
  found: this::readAllLines
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in method reference
      java.util.List<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your method

```
private Stream<String> readAllLines(Path path) {
    try (Stream<String> fileContent = Files.lines(path)) {
        return fileContent;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The very purpose of the `try( … )` construct is to close the resource when leaving the block. You are returning a closed stream.

At this place, you should consider the [documentation of `flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)):

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.

Hence, you don’t need to close the stream returned in a `flatMap` function, the Stream implementation will do.

So in this context, use

```
private Stream<String> readAllLines(Path path) {
    try {
        return Files.lines(path);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

By the way, you are looping over the `keySet()` of a `Map` to perform a `get` lookup for each, just to process the values only. That’s quiet inefficient, considering that you can iterate over the [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) in the first place, if that’s the only thing you’re interested in. (You can use [`entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) if you need both) You may even use a stream at this place, simplifying the entire operation to:

```
public void readLogs() {
    try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get("."))) {
        stream.filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".log"))
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(path -> {
                  final String s = path.getFileName().toString();
                  return s.substring(0, s.indexOf("."));
              }))
              .values().stream()
              .flatMap(List::stream)
              .flatMap(path -> {
                  try { return Files.lines(path); }
                  catch (IOException e) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e); }
              })
              .forEachOrdered(this::parseLogLine);
    } catch(IOException|UncheckedIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that since you are using the grouping only to determine the order you may also use `sort` instead:

```
public void readLogs() {
    try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get("."))) {
        stream.filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".log"))
              .sorted(Comparator.comparing(path -> {
                  final String s = path.getFileName().toString();
                  return s.substring(0, s.indexOf("."));
              }))
              .flatMap(path -> {
                  try { return Files.lines(path); }
                  catch (IOException e) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e); }
              })
              .forEachOrdered(this::parseLogLine);
    } catch(IOException|UncheckedIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and you can simplify this by sorting by the entire file name as that implies being sorted by their common prefix including the part up to the first dot:

```
public void readLogs() {
    try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get("."))) {
        stream.filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".log"))
              .sorted(Comparator.comparing(path -> path.getFileName().toString()))
              .flatMap(path -> {
                  try { return Files.lines(path); }
                  catch (IOException e) { throw new UncheckedIOException(e); }
              })
              .forEachOrdered(this::parseLogLine);
    } catch(IOException|UncheckedIOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Note that since you are using the grouping only to determine the order` - `. collect(Collectors.groupingBy..)` returns a map but we don't pass a `mapFactory`. Then how do you say it is used to determine the order?

Comment: @user7 `groupingBy` without a map factory doesn’t guaranty an order of the groups, but when streaming over the resulting map in a `.values() .stream()
.flatMap(List::stream)` fashion, all elements of a group are adjacent to each other and since this is the only difference to the original stream here, it is merely an ordering operation, not a sorting, not producing a total order, however, it’s an operation that can be replaced by a sorting operation to achieve the same effect. The sorting provides stronger guarantees than the grouping, but still also achieves the clustering the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks. Just noticed OP's `pathsByThread`. So, the intent is to group logs by thread names and I agree that sorting makes much more sense here.